# Create a menu side bar that causes non-side bar items or content to be resized

Tags: jquery, html, css

Using css grid, my page has 3 columns and 1 row. When the page first loads, only the content in columns 1 &2 show. Column 3 isn’t.

What I want to achieve:

When a user clicks a button in columns 2, column 3 appears by Sliding in from the right, causing the content boxes of columns 1 and 2 to shrink in size (this is to accommodate columns 3 which is the menu side bar ).

What I’ve tried:

1. Set the with of columns 1 and 2 using viewport width and calc() to subtract a certain amount of pixels. This doesn’t work so well since it depends on the screen and won’t fill the entire screen sometimes.
2. Change the width of the grid containers using jquery’s css method

I’m using jquery, but any way this can be solved is acceptable

Output:

The end result should be like how google calendar appears on the side when a user click on calendar. Similar to Gmail.

Please pardon the typos, I’m using safari on my phone

Comment: Have heard about flexbox? This is insanely easy to achieve with flex or bootstrap 4 grid.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Flex. Specifically flex-grow: 1. On click add a class active to hide/show the last column.

```css
.box-wrapper {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: stretch;
}


.box {
  background: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.box3 {display: none}

.active {
display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrapper">
  <div class="box">
  tetst
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  tt
  </div>
  <div class="box box3 active">
  ts
  </div>
</div>
```